# Workbooks-specific regional settings : Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel, regional-settings

The two links below are examples on how to handle regional setting issues in excel vba.

I'm looking for a way to run a workbook with full regional settings based English-US, no matter what the OS says, covering both the date format and the comma/dot issue.

Am I right to think that such 'one strike solution' is just not possible?

https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/41533-controlling-windows-regional-settings-visual-basic-applications.html